# VBA/Error 1004: Delete method of Class Range failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am yet again faced with this error 1004; I was given some [very good answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489590/vba-method-delete-of-class-range-failed/73489912?noredirect=1#comment129778558_73489912), that I now am trying to apply to a bigger and more "complex" sub.

I first get my `Agence` name from my macro-wielding workbook `owb`. I then open both files I need to use afetrwards. I cycle through the first one using a range RngDate, use the `Union` method to gather all `CellDate`s from before 1st of July 2021 in my range `Poubelle` (trash). Once I'm out of the `RngFact` loop, I simply use the `.Delete` method and it works just fine.

I later on cycle through all my clients using another range (`RngClient`), and for each of them I cycle once again through all my bills (factures in french) in the range `RngFact` to find theirs, and after getting the information I need I add the bill I just studied to the `Poubelle`/trash.  But when I try to use `.Delete` once I'm out of the loop using the range/cells/worksheet I want to delete, it brings back `error 1004`. I isolated the line triggering the RTE1004 in the code. Even though I am now "only" in a loop using my agency's sheet (`wba`) itself in a loop using my macro's sheet (`owb`), both unaffected by the `.Delete` operation.

edit: I am doing so because I have to go through dozens of thoushands of lines each time, so if each iteration can remove a few lines each time it helps a lot. (end of edit)

I wracked my brain but I do not comprehend what's the difference between the case that works and the one that doesn't. Please help me! (again ;-;)

(I do realize using this many loops is probably inefficient but heh it worked so far)

```
Sub GrosTas()

Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\QNS691\Documents\Excel\par agence 3\"
Dim y As Integer: y = 0
Dim owb As Workbook: Set owb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ows As Worksheet: Set ows = owb.Worksheets("Feuil1")
Dim PremAg As Range: Set PremAg = ows.Range("X2")
Dim LastAg As Range: Set LastAg = ows.Range("X" & ows.Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row)
Dim RngAg As Range: Set RngAg = ows.Range(PremAg, LastAg)

Dim CellClient As Range
Dim CellDate As Range
Dim CellFact As Range
Dim Agence As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim RngClient As Range
Dim RngDate As Range
Dim RngFact As Range
Dim Poubelle As Range
Dim ID As Integer
Dim M_H As Integer
Dim N_H As Integer
Dim M_E As Integer
Dim N_E As Integer
Dim prevdate As String
Dim mois As Integer
Dim Ligne As Integer


For Each CellAg In RngAg

    Agence = CStr(CellAg.Value)
    If Len(Agence) > 0 Then
    
        FilePathAg = FolderPath & Agence & ".xlsx"
        FilePathFact = FolderPath & "\fact\F_" & Agence & ".xlsx"
        If Len(Dir(FilePathAg)) > 0 And Len(Dir(FilePathFact)) > 0 Then
        
            Set wba = Workbooks.Open(FilePathAg)
            Set wsa = wba.Worksheets(1)
            Set wbf = Workbooks.Open(FilePathFact)
            Set wsf = wbf.Worksheets(1)
            Set RngClient = wsa.Range("B2", wsa.Cells(wsa.Cells(wsa.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "B"))
            Set RngDate = wsf.Range("M2", wsf.Cells(wsf.Cells(wsf.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row, "M"))
            For Each CellDate In RngDate
            
                If IsDate(CellDate) Then
                
                    If CellDate.Value < CDate("01/07/2021") Then
                    
                        y = y + 1
                        If Poubelle Is Nothing Then
                        
                            Set Poubelle = CellDate
                        Else
                        
                            Set Poubelle = Union(Poubelle, CellDate)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next CellDate
            
            If Not Poubelle Is Nothing Then
            
                Poubelle.EntireRow.Delete   ' THIS ONE WORKS JUST FINE
            End If
            Set Poubelle = Nothing
            
            With wsa
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(14).Clear
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(13).Clear
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(12).Clear
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(11).Clear
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(10).Clear
            .Range("Tableau1").Columns(9).Clear
            End With
            
            For Each CellClient In RngClient
            
                ID = CellClient.Value
                M_H = 0
                N_H = 0
                M_E = 0
                N_E = 0
                prevdate = ""
                Set RngFact = wsf.Range("K2", wsf.Cells(wsf.Cells(wsf.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row, "K"))
                For Each CellFact In RngFact
                
                    If CellClient = CellFact Then
                    
                        mois = Month(wsf.Range("M" & CellFact.Row))
                        If mois >= 3 And mois <= 8 Then
                        
                            If Not wsf.Range("M" & CellFact.Row) = prevdate Then
                            
                                prevdate = wsf.Range("M" & CellFact.Row)
                                N_E = N_E + 1
                            End If
                            M_E = M_E + wsf.Range("T" & CellFact.Row)
                        Else
                        
                            If Not wsf.Range("M" & CellFact.Row) = prevdate Then
                            
                                prevdate = wsf.Range("M" & CellFact.Row)
                                N_H = N_H + 1
                            End If
                            M_H = M_H + wsf.Range("T" & CellFact.Row)
                        End If
                        If Poubelle Is Nothing Then
                        
                            Set Poubelle = CellFact
                        Else
                                               
                            Set Poubelle = Union(Poubelle, CellFact)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next CellFact
                
                If Not Poubelle Is Nothing Then
                






                    Poubelle.EntireRow.Delete   'THIS ONE IS RESISTING DELETION






                End If
                Set Poubelle = Nothing
                
                With wsa
                .Cells(CellClient, 9) = M_E
                .Cells(CellClient, 10) = N_E
                .Cells(CellClient, 11) = M_H
                .Cells(CellClient, 12) = N_H
                .Cells(CellClient, 13) = M_E + M_H
                .Cells(CellClient, 14) = N_E + N_H
                End With
                
            Next CellClient
        End If
    End If
    
    With wsa
    Ligne = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("I" & Ligne).Select ' = "=SOUS.TOTAL(109;[Marge Ete])"
    .Range("I" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(9))
    .Range("J" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(10))
    .Range("K" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(11))
    .Range("L" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(12))
    .Range("M" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(13))
    .Range("N" & Ligne) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, .Range("Tableau1").Columns(14))
    End With
    
    wba.Close SaveChanges:=True
    wbf.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next CellAg

MsgBox y

End Sub
```

Comment: the line with the comment `'THIS ONE IS RESISTING`. I'll isolate it in the code

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You mean, in place of `Set Poubelle = Nothing` right after the successful deletion?

Comment: It somehow adds one value when it passes through the first line (`Count = 1`), and it jumps all the way to `Count = 32768` when it goes through the second one, and in the ned the error is still the same.

Comment: If you check the value of `Poubelle` with `Debug.Print Poubell.Address`, are you getting a valid or expected union of cells?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @PeterT 
`Debug.Print` does show a completely normal range, which corresponds to what I need to delete. When filtering for my first client's bills manually, I find lines 957 to 961 and 2415 to 2418, which is the same range my Poubelle contains.